# Finding name from max value in an object array of mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I have mongodb query which I am working with pymongo.

The dictionary collection is as follows:

```
{'_id': 0,
 'name': 'aimee Zank',
 'scores': [{'score': 94.463179736705023, 'type': 'exam'},
  {'score': 88.78273309957772, 'type': 'quiz'},
  {'score': 95.8740349954354, 'type': 'homework'}]}

{'_id': 1,
 'name': 'Tomas Jude',
 'scores': [{'score': 55.9736705023, 'type': 'exam'},
  {'score': 50.78273309957772, 'type': 'quiz'},
  {'score': 45.8740349954354, 'type': 'homework'}]}

{"_id":2,
"name": "Corliss Zuk",
"scores": [{"score":67.03077096065002,"type":"exam"},
{"score":6.301851677835235,"type":"quiz"},
{"score":66.28344683278382,"type":"homework"}]}
```

The query is this: I need to find the name of student who scored max in all score type (exam, quiz and homework).  From the above dictionary, I need to extract aimee Zank as that person scored most in all 3 types. I have done it using function and extracting the name for each type as shown below.

```
def max_result(type):
  max_result=Collection.aggregate([
      {"$unwind" : "$scores" },
    {"$match": {"scores.type": type}},
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id" : "null",
            "name": {"$first": "$name"},
            "max_marks" : {"$max":"$scores.score"},
        }
    }
  ])
  return max_result

max_marks_exam = [i for i in max_result("exam")]
max_marks_quiz = [i for i in max_result("quiz")]
max_marks_homework = [i for i in max_result("homework")]

print(max_marks_exam[0])
print(max_marks_quiz[0])
print(max_marks_homework[0])
```

The result comes as:

```
{'_id': 'null', 'name': 'aimee Zank', 'max_marks': 94.463179736705023}
{'_id': 'null', 'name': 'aimee Zank', 'max_marks': 88.78273309957772}
{'_id': 'null', 'name': 'aimee Zank', 'max_marks': 95.8740349954354}
```

How to get all into one? Meaning the code should extract max value of each type and throw me the name.

Answer (score 0):

My example isn't very elegant, but I think it produces the output you want, or at least something you can easily modify/extend to get the output you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$scores" },
  { "$group": {
      "_id": "$scores.type",
      "nameScores": {
        "$push": { "name": "$name", "score": "$scores.score" }
      },
      "max": { "$max": "$scores.score" }
    }
  },
  { "$set": {
      "max_score": {
        "$first": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$nameScores",
            "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.score", "$max" ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "type": "$_id",
      "max_score": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example output:

```js
[
  {
    "max_score": { "name": "aimee Zank", "score": 88.78273309957773 },
    "type": "quiz"
  },
  {
    "max_score": { "name": "aimee Zank", "score": 95.8740349954354 },
    "type": "homework"
  },
  {
    "max_score": { "name": "aimee Zank", "score": 94.46317973670503 },
    "type": "exam"
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zTcqkxtSTkn).